# Strange Behaviour Spring Jpa with native query and union select

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

The idea is to have the same Repository to query all the types of the contracts that come from different tables. Here, I used 3 tables to explain the problem :

I have this JPA entity

```java
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ContractEntity {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "c_reference")
  private String cReference;

  @Column(name = "c_number")
  private String cNumber;

  @Column(name = "c_index")
  private Integer cIndex;
}
```

And the Spring Boot Repository class is

```java
@Repository
public interface ContractClientRepository
    extends CrudRepository<ContractEntity, String> {
  // mssql native query
  @Query(
      value =
          """
              SELECT co_reference AS c_reference, null AS c_number, 1 AS c_index
              FROM contract10, client ...
              WHERE ...
                AND email = :email

              UNION

              SELECT contract_reference AS c_reference, null AS c_number, 2 AS c_index
              FROM contract20, client ...
              WHERE ...
                AND email = :email

              UNION

              SELECT ref AS c_reference, null AS c_number, role AS c_index
              FROM contract30, client ...
              WHERE ...
                AND email = :email
                 """,
      nativeQuery = true)
  List<ContractEntity> findByEmail(@Param("email") String email);
}
```

The code works well, but I have strange behavior due to a problem in data:

```
contract10
c_reference|c_number|c_index
00AAAABBBBB|null    |null
```

```
contract30
c_reference|c_number|c_index
00AAAABBBBB|123456  |4
```

When the same reference is found twice on the tables contract10 and contract30, the repository returns a list of 2 objects with the same objet. For my case it was `[{00AAAABBBBB, null, null}, {00AAAABBBBB, null, null}]` instead of `[{00AAAABBBBB, null, null}, {00AAAABBBBB, 123456, 4}]`!

How can I do to fix this ?